# Excel custom data validation with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I am trying to limit a field to inputs greater than 0 and less than or equal to 1

Comment: Look at `Data Validation` on the `Data` ribbon. There is a setting to allow `Decimal` values between your settings.

Comment: The issue with that function is that it includes the minimum value and me setting 0.01 or 0.001 just is not good enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.
Seeing as how the custom datavalidation only needs a true statement i did the following where "A1" is the field i am doing data validation on

Custom data validation
=AND(A1<=1;A1>0)
this formula returns true if the value in the cell is greater than 0 and less than or equal to 1